# How to get key of two biggest value of the following type of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, max

I have a dictionary of this type:

For that, I would like to get the two keys (A, B, or C) with the two biggest "registered times", in a specific "country" and on a specific "date". However, I don't get A, B, C but the values as output.

My code so far:

```
def selected(data, country, date):
    lst = []
    for key in data:
        if data[key]['country'] == country:
            date_chosen = date
            lst.append(data[key]['registered times'][date_chosen])
            lst.sort()
    return [lst[-1], lst[-2]]

data = {
        'A': {"name": "Tim",
              "country": "Canada",
              "registered times": {"11-05-2020": 1000, "10-05-2020": 1100, "09-05-2020": 5000},
              "language": "English"},
        'B': {"name": "Lisa",
              "country": "Germany",
              "registered times": {"11-05-2020": 2000, "10-05-2020": 1400, "09-05-2020": 3000},
              "language": "English"},
        'C': {"name": "Simon",
              "country": "Canada",
              "registered times": {"11-05-2020": 1400, "10-05-2020": 1300, "09-05-2020": 2000},
              "language": "English"},
        }

#Test the code:
selected(data, "Canada", "09-05-2020")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add to `lst` not only the value, but a tuple of key and value. At the end you can sort the list by values and returns the keys.

```
def selected(data, country, date):
    lst = []
    for key in data:
        if data[key]['country'] == country:
            date_chosen = date
            lst.append((key, data[key]['registered times'][date_chosen])) # appending a pair
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) # sorting by values
    return [lst[-1][0], lst[-2][0]]  # returning keys

data = {
        'A': {"name": "Tim",
                            "country": "Canada",
                            "registered times": {"11-05-2020": 1000, "10-05-2020": 1100, "09-05-2020": 5000},
                            "language": "English"},
        'B': {"name": "Lisa",
                            "country": "Germany",
                            "registered times": {"11-05-2020": 2000, "10-05-2020": 1400, "09-05-2020": 3000},
                            "language": "English"},
        'C': {"name": "Simon",
                            "country": "Canada",
                            "registered times": {"11-05-2020": 1400, "10-05-2020": 1300, "09-05-2020": 2000},
                            "language": "English"},
        }  

#Test the code:
print(selected(data, "Canada", "09-05-2020"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `selected()` function can be simplified by only doing the sort once:

```
def selected(data, country, date):
    lst = []
    for key in data:
        if data[key]['country'] == country:
            date_chosen = date
            lst.append((key, data[key]['registered times'][date_chosen]))
    lst.sort(key=lambda x:-x[1])
    return lst[:2]
```

Also just returning a slice of the first two items is more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 problems , first you add all data as element of the list , you can do this to make it as a map using the key :

`lst.append(key,data[key]['registered times'][date_chosen])`

and secondly you dont sort using the date , you can do it with a lambda expression to sort with the second element which is the date in your case :

`lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])`